# Role "postgres" does not exist

Tags: python-3.x, docker-compose

I currently have a postgres docker container running here.

[image: Docker Container]

I am currently building the container with following docker-compose file

```
version: "3.4"

services:   postgresql:
    image: postgres:14.2-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "password#"
      POSTGRES_DB: dbname
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

    volumes:
      - ./scripts/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

when I go to run the following using the python library psycopg2.

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='quitgaming' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='Coldwell980869#'")

print(conn)
```

I get the error:

```
 conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
```

I am wondering what this error is as I currently am building the database with the dbUser as postgres and 2 if I need to something different what would that be? What would I need to add to my docker-compose? Thanks in advance.